# SPA, check current pending fetch requests with fetch API or event or with Apollo

Tags: javascript, request, fetch, single-page-application, apollo

Coming from `jQuery` I know I can use `jQuery.active` to check the number of active jQuery AJAX connections; I have to constantly poll that var in order to have an event fired in the advent of a new connection. I can also use `jQuery.ajaxStart()` and `jQuery.ajaxStop()` events.

I'm building an SPA with GraphQL and Apollo (https://github.com/apollographql).

Apollo Link (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link) is the layer which effectively starts GET/POST requests.

Is there any way to verify that requests are pending?

Here a user tried it: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/236 using this code:

```js
const queryInProcessNotifier = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  client.mutate({mutation:M_CHANGE_APP_SETTING, variables: { setting:"appIsLoading", state:true }})
  return forward(operation).map((data) => {
    client.mutate({mutation:M_CHANGE_APP_SETTING, variables: { setting:"appIsLoading", state:false }})
    return data
  })
})
```

It works because every request passes through there, but if it were to be interrupted for any reason my status would no longer change to `false`.

Also I have many parallel requests to check, so I can create a "counter" +1 / -1 for each request, but still the problem with the interrupted ones.

What do you think about?

Is there a way without libraries at all?

Is there a `fetch` API or event to subscribe?

Comment: I don't think that is [currently possible](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/40).